# Basic Search Pattern that matches an 8 digit identifier using letters A - Z (4 chars) and numbers 0 - 0 (4 chars)?

Tags: php, regex

no code required just the expression thats all.

I have come up with this and it works a treat and have tried to see if it fails the rule.

basically a product ID is 8 characters,  The first 4 MUST be letters A-Z and the last 4 MUST be digits 0 - 9.

```
ABCD1234 = TRUE ( valid )
ABCD9999 = TRUE ( valid )
XETB3345 = TRUE ( valid )
FI35D099 = FALSE ( not valid)
```

here is my expression that makes the above work:

```
/[A-Z]{4}[1-9]{4}/
```

now what I want to do is extend this so that it allows lowercase a-z also.

I then want to go to an advanced stage where the pattern should match an 8 digit string that contains A-Za-z and 1-9 and in any order.

so something like this should become valid

```
aB90s2W8
92iL22sD
a9FF3i2
etc.
```

Comment: To allow for lowercase use the `i` modifier `/[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}/i`; for any combination just use `/[A-Z0-9]{8}/i` Note you should be using `[0-9]` not `[1-9]`

Comment: yes thats right, the 'i' modifier, arguably the most important pattern modifier you can use with regular expressions in php!

How I forgot about it i'll never know.. thanks Nick, for sharing btw.  You've put me back on the right path.

Comment: no worries - be sure to note what Jan said about anchors in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some anchors as well:

```
^(?i)[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/qmTzU0/2/).

---

For your other requirement, use

```
^(?i)[A-Z0-9]{8}$
```

See another [**example on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/qmTzU0/3/) as well.

---

Explanation:

```
^           # start of string / line in multiline mode
(?i)        # inline modifier, turning on case insensitivity
[A-Z0-9]{8} # a-zA-Z0-9, exactly 8 times
$           # end of string / line in multiline mode
```

Comment: Great stuff Jan. Thanks again. I'll give them both a try.

Comment: my only issue with ^(?i)[A-Z0-9]{8}$,  i got this while experimenting myself but I failed to understand the logic in why it works.

This is how I'm reading the expression Jan, let me know if its pretty much the way you read it too:

start of string = ^
start of sub pattern = (
it may or may not be case-sensitive = ?i
end of sub pattern = )
start of character class = [
range of uppercase chars A through to Z = A-Z
range of digits 0 to 9 = 0-9
end of character class = ]
total chars to match is 8 = {8}
end of string = $

Comment: @MannyD: I added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks again Jan, much appreciated sir.